# How to solve user logout when updating the password?

Tags: python, django

I created a user profile update page. There are several fields like name, surname, email, profile picture and password. If you leave the password field blank, parts other than the password can be updated. If you If you want to change the password, you can fill in the password field.

When a user updates their fields other than the password, the page redirects the user to the homepage, which is something we want. But when the user wants to change the password, the user gets logout and redirect to the logout page. How can I fix it and redirect the user to the homepage?

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def update_user(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=id)
    form = SignUpChangeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        if form.cleaned_data['password1'] != "":
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()
        return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "update_user.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required=False,
                                label="New Password (leave blank if you do not want to change it)",
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required=False,
                                label="New Password Confirmation (leave blank if you do not want to change it)",
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'image')
        widgets = {
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SignUpChangeForm, self).clean()
        if cleaned_data['password1'] != cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise ValidationError("Password confirmation does not match!")
        return cleaned_data
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True, null= True, default='profile.png')
    isUserActive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log the user in again:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

@login_required
def update_user(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=id)
    form = SignUpChangeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        if form.cleaned_data['password1'] != "":
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'update_user.html', context)
```

It is however not really clear why you pass an `id` to the view. Right now everyone can edit *another* user, since I simply have to login and use the id of another user to change their password. Why not work with `request.user` as the instance?

---

> **Note**: Usually it is *not* a good idea to work with `SignUpChangeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)`.
> It is possible that you make a POST request with no data, but still valid, for example if no
> fields are required. Normally you check if it is a POST request, and then construct a form with `SignUpChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.

Comment: It works! And thank you for your advices. I change my view as  `user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=request.user.id)`

Comment: @edece: but why not `user = request.user`? If that is the user model, `request.user` is already a `UserProfile` object.

Comment: Oh, you are right then just `user = request.user` will work